# Conventional notation: $\vec{a^T}\vec{a} = ||\vec{a}||$ or $\vec{a^T}\vec{a} = ||\vec{a}||^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Just want to make sure I grasp the conventional notation on this once and for all.

If I recollect correctly the following should be correct, right?:
$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a} = \vec{a^T}\vec{a} = ||\vec{a}||^2$

But I'm not sure if I've actually seen this relationship in some places, which is in conflict with the above. So this must be wrong or am I missing something?:

$\vec{a^T}\vec{a} = ||\vec{a}||$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct one is
$$
\vec a^T \vec a = \|\vec a\|^2.
$$
The intuition behind this is that the quantity on the left is quadratic with respect to $\vec a$, so the right hand side must be quadratic as well (which would not be the case for $\|\vec a\|$): Take real $t>0$, then
$$
(t\vec a)^T(t\vec a) = t^2 \vec a^T \vec a = t^2 \|\vec a\|^2  = \|t \vec a\|^2 
$$
holds for all $t>0$.  This computation would not work with the incorrect $\vec a^T \vec a = \|\vec a\|$.